# How to search for all txt files in a directory (including subfolders)

Tags: cmd

I want a command that can look through all the subfolders of a directory and compile all the contents of the txt files into one.

I have a code that does this for a folder.

```
@echo on
erase Compiled.txt
type *.txt>> Compiled.txt
```

How do I make it so that it looks through all subfolders as well?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
dir /s /b /a:-d *.txt
```

might do the trick for ya :)

Comment: Hi, sorry I wasn't clear enough. This just gives me the file names. I want to add all the CONTENTS of the txt files into one.

Comment: At the time of providing the answer, the question did not contain the wording contents and was correct at that time, but as the question is edited it is no longer correct

Answer (score 0):

Since the other one line answer does not cut it, start from reading

`> For /?`

then try

```
@echo on
erase Compiled.txt
For /R %%f in (*.txt) do echo type "%%f"
```

to see behaviour
then if happy remove echo and add your redirection >> Compiled.txt

Just beware that very simplistic approach means that compiled.txt may also be embedded thus use either >> Compiled.TEXT (and rename as last step) OR output to a non included folder like >>"..\Compiled.txt"

Answer (score 0):

If you can use PowerShell, this might do it.

```
$CompiledFile = '.\Compiled.txt'
if (Test-Path -Path $CompiledFile) { Remove-Item -Path $CompiledFile }
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Filter '*.txt' |
    ForEach-Object {
        Get-Content $_.FullName | Out-File -FilePath $CompiledFile -Encoding ascii -Append
    }
```

If you must run in the 1987 vintage cmd.exe, it can be twisted into a usable form.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "$CompiledFile = '.\Compiled.txt'" ^
    "if (Test-Path -Path $CompiledFile) { Remove-Item -Path $CompiledFile }" ^
    "Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Filter '*.txt' |" ^
    "    ForEach-Object {" ^
    "        Get-Content $_.FullName | Out-File -FilePath $CompiledFile -Encoding ascii -Append" ^
    "    }"
```